# How to to create a new rails app using scaffold command with only a json interface (to use with angularjs)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'd like to create a RESTful application with ruby on rails, but I also use angularjs, so I'd like to scaffold a new model with controller having only json request and return.

This should skip any html.erb views to be created and also skip the html render in the controller.

How can I do that?

Comment: Try the Rails 5 beta. It has rails-api built into it. Or try rails-api ;)

Comment: @DavidK-J it lets you do that level of specificity?  Nice.

Comment: Yep, http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html

Answer (score 0):

Using rails 5:

```
$ rails new my_api --api
```

using rails 4:

```
rails new my_api -T
```

Comment: Ok, and if I want just a few controllers behave like an api but other send both?  Can I do that too?

Comment: then you need a normal rails project, but you have to tell your controllers to render json response.